# Ract Native Animated API : I can't move the element correctly and leave a space between the elements while using the react native Animated API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, react-animations

I am trying to implement this carousel in React Native

[image]

and use React Native Animated to implement it.
I wrote the code as follows

```
     const itemSize = AppDevice.width / 4;
     const marginValue = 5;

   const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
   let videoRef = useRef();
   const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
   const marginX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
   let carouselRef = useRef();
   let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
   let [MainCategory, setMainCategory] = useState();
   let [currentIndex, setcurrentIndex] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
    const renderCarousel = () => {
     return (
   <Animated.FlatList
    data={MainCategory}
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    snapToInterval={itemSize + marginValue * 2}
    bounces={false}
    decelerationRate={0}
    style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    onScroll={Animated.event(
      [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: scrollX}}}],
      {useNativeDriver: true},
    )}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={e =>
      setcurrentIndex(
        Math.ceil(
     e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x /(itemSize + marginValue * 2),//to find active item
        ),
      )
    }
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
      const inputRange = [
        (index - 2) * (itemSize + marginValue * 2), //Before 2 items of the active item
        (index - 1) * (itemSize + marginValue * 2), //Before 1 items of the active item
        index * (itemSize + marginValue * 2),       //active item
        (index + 1) * (itemSize + marginValue * 2),//after 1 items of the active item
        (index + 2) * (itemSize + marginValue * 2),//after 2 items of the active item
      ];

      const translateY = scrollX.interpolate({   //To change the size of items
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [0.6, 0.9, 1.25, 0.9, 0.6],  
      });

      const inputRange2 = [   
        (index - 2) * (itemSize + marginValue),
        (index - 1) * (itemSize + marginValue),
        index * (itemSize + marginValue),
        (index + 1) * (itemSize + marginValue),
        (index + 2) * (itemSize + marginValue),
      ];
      const margin = marginX.interpolate({   //to add margine to items  ((Here it does 
                                                not work as expectedcorrectly
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [-20, 10, 0, 10, -20],   // 
      });
      return (
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            marginTop: 50,
            width: itemSize,
            height: itemSize,
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            marginHorizontal:
              index != 0 && index + 1 != MainCategory.length    //to center first item
                ? marginValue
                : 0,
            marginStart:
              index == 0
                ? itemSize * 2 - itemSize / 2 + marginValue
                : marginValue,
            marginEnd:                                          //to center last item
              index + 1 == MainCategory.length
                ? itemSize + itemSize / 2 - marginValue
                : marginValue,
            padding: 20,
            borderRadius: 20,
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            transform: [{scale: translateY}, {translateX: margin}],
          }}>
          <Image
            style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', resizeMode: 'contain'}}
            source={require('../assets/images/open-box.png')}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      );
    }}
  />
);
 };
   return (
   <View style={{flex: 1}}>
   {renderCarousel()}
   </View>
 );
 };
```

The size changes as expected, but the problem is that I want to leave spaces between the elements, but it does not work for me as expected

[image]

Is there anyone who can help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found I just replaced the ref, from `marginX` to `scrollX`